# Django - 'Paginator' object has no attribute 'get_page'

Tags: django

I am trying to use paginator for the first time on my Django project. I am having problems getting it to work. When I run it I get the error

> AttributeError: 'Paginator' object has no attribute 'get_page'.

I cannot seem to resolve it. plz help me

```
def index(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', '1')
    posts = BoardTbl.objects.raw(  # ORM 미사용
        'SELECT b.idx, u.last_name, u.first_name, b.subject, b.content, b.date '
        'FROM board_tbl b '
        'JOIN auth_user u '
        'ON b.writer = u.id'
    )
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 15)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
    #count = len(list(posts));
    context = {'posts': page_obj}
    # return render(request, 'post/index.html', {'posts':posts, 'count':count})
    return render(request, 'post/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you print the `Paginator.__mro__` in your view, and [edit] the question with the respnse?

Comment: What version of Django does he use ?

Comment: @HSNHK my django version == 1.11.16

Answer (score 0):

This method differs in different versions

Version 1.11 :

```
page_obj = paginator.page(page)
```

For example version 3 :

```
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
```

document :

[Version 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)

[Version 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view-function)

Comment: sir, I edited get_page --> page, but, server result showed "object of type 'RawQuerySet' has no len()"

Comment: I think if you turn it into a list, the problem will be solved : paginator = Paginator(list(posts), 15)

Comment: thank you sir, i solved this problem thank you my god